# Ignore word spelling on a per-file/buffer basis

Tags: spell-checking, sessions, viminfo

I can add a word to the local dictionary or `spellfile` with `zg`.

I can use `zG` to add a word to the internal spellfile, but this still affects all loaded files.

How can I add spelling exceptions on a per-file or per-buffer basis, and have it still work when re-opening the file?

Is there some `.viminfo` magic for this?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built-in; I guess the reasoning is that spelling (at least for a certain language) is inherently global. Any differences should be reflected in the language / dialect chosen.

You can implement such buffer-local spelling exception yourself: Get a temp file via `tempname()`, prepend it to `'spellfile'`, and then `zg` / `1zg` will place the exception there. This would be local to a single Vim session (like `zG`).

If you would like persistent buffer-local spelling, instead of `tempname()`, either put the spell file next to the file (`bufname('') . '.spl'`), or place then all into a dedicated spell directory, encoding the original file path in a way that `:mkview` does: replace the path separator with `=+` and `=` with `==`. So, `~/foo/bar.txt` would get a spellfile of `/path/to/spelldir/~=+foo=+bar.txt.spl`

Comment: Thanks - sorry to move the goal-posts, but I intended to have the ignored words persist across sessions. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, okay. Then you would exchange `tempname()` with something more static. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks - I get your logic, but I don't know how to implement your dedicated spell directory solution. How do I do this replacement?

Comment: At least in gvim there is a way to do temporary (sessions-based) spell ignores with `zG` (for anyone reading this wanted that like I did): https://superuser.com/a/133228/1023666

Comment: Oh, sorry - just noticed that was in the original post (too often, I skip to the answers)!